# How to substitute spaces with %20 in a substring of a line across multiple files using sed, awk, grep etc

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

In a recent update neomutt changed how it handles regexp matching and it's breaking my notmuch URI's in my config. The solution seems to be replacing the spaces in the URI with `%20`. This wouldn't be a huge deal except that I have a lot of virtual mailboxes defined across multiple config files. So here is a sample of one config:

```
"Inbox"                 "notmuch://?query=folder:gmail/INBOX and tag:inbox" \
"Drafts"                "notmuch://?query=folder:gmail/Drafts" \
"Sent Mail"             "notmuch://?query=folder:gmail/Sent%20Mail" \
"Trash"                 "notmuch://?query=folder:gmail/Trash" \
"Today"                 "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and date:today" \
"Yesterday"             "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and date:yesterday" \
"This Week"             "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and date:this_week" \
"Todo"                  "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and tag:todo" \
"Starred"               "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and tag:star" \
"Burning Man"           'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/Burning Man"' \
"  Work List"           'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/Burning Man/Work List"' \
"ATXHS"                 'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/ATX Hackerspace" and not tag:archive' \
"  ATXHS Members"       'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/ATX Hackerspace/Members" and not tag:archive' \
"  ATXHS Discuss"       'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/ATX Hackerspace/Discuss" and not tag:archive' \
"  ATXHS Announce"      'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/ATX Hackerspace/Announce" and not tag:archive'
```

Using `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, or whatever, how do I change `"gmail/ATX Hackerspace"` to `"gmail/ATX%20Hackerspace"` without effecting `" and not tag:archive"`?

I know that other changes need to be made, but this is the only one that I'm stuck on. Basically, I need to change the spaces between `folder:"` and the next instance of a double quote. I don't know if this can even be done reasonably.

Comment: Can't you just do `sed 's!gmail/ATX Hackerspace!gmail/ATX%20Hackerspace!'`? Oh, you have my vote.

Comment: Welcome on SO, on SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, kindly do so and let us know then(not my downvote BTW).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis - apparently not; there are other spaces that must be converted too, not just the one you identified.

Comment: @mathguy is right. This was just a sample, so the answer has to apply to any similar entries. For instance, your solution would not correct the `gmail/Burning Man` entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on *I need to change the space**s** between `folder:"` and the next instance of a double quote*, the following seems to be a very easy and fairly readable solution:

```
sed -E ':a;s/(folder:"[^ "]*) /\1%20/;ta' yourinput
```

It is basically a while loop where

- the body `s/(folder:"[^ "]*) /\1%20/` tries to pick the first, if any, space that follows `folder:"` before the closing `"`,
- the condition to *repeat* the loop is that the attempt was successful (i.e. the substitution was done indeed); `ta` indeed `t`ests if any `s` command was successful on the current line and, if this is the case, it transfer the control to the line labelled `:a`.

**Update**

Concerning the `-E` option, I have tested the answer above **only** on GNU sed. Ed Morton has tested it on OSX/BSD and the command I provided gives an unchanged output.

I thought the reason could be `-E`, or maybe a missing `;` after `ta`, but this does not seem to be the case, based on Ed Morton's attempts.

I initially thought the command was POSIX-compliant, based on a the following excerpt from GNU sed's man page:

> ```
> -E, -r, --regexp-extended
>
>               use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability
>               use POSIX -E).
> ```

Furhtermore on [this GNU page](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html), I read

> Historically this was a GNU extension, but the -E extension has since
> been added to the POSIX standard
> (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use -E for
> portability.

Up to this point, however, this is what **GNU** says of **POSIX**.

If you go to that link, the last line in the **Issue history** section is dated *2020-03-18 15:37* and reads *Resolved => Applied*, but I don't know how that sites relates to POSIX.

The bottom line is: **I don't know if `-E` is POSIX-compliant.**

Comment: Yes! This is it! I knew it had to be something like this. Thanks!

Comment: You should mention that that will only work n GNU sed.

Comment: idk, the only awks that support `-E` AFAIK are GNU awk and OSX/BSD (MacOS) awk and I just tried it on both and GNU awk produced desired output while the OSX/BSD one just reproduced the input with no changes.

Comment: My GNU sed has this line with reference to the `-E`/`-r`/`--regexp-extended` option: _use extended regular expressions in the script *(for portability use POSIX -E)*_, so I guess POSIX sed *does* support `-E`.

Comment: POSIX doesn't mention a `-E` option - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html. Even if it did though, that particular script doesn't work with other seds that DO support `-E` such as OSX/BSD sed.

Comment: great but `-E` isn't the only issue - idk what it is since I only use s, g, and p commands in sed but the script is apparently doing something else that's GNU-specific since it doesn't work in OSX/BSD sed with `-E`. It'd be fine just to say "it's GNU sed only" and leave it at that, just some kind of heads up for others trying to use it in future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212284/discussion-between-enrico-maria-de-angelis-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/folder:"[^"]+"/) {
    tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/ /,"%20",tgt)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
 } 1' file
"Inbox"                 "notmuch://?query=folder:gmail/INBOX and tag:inbox" \
"Drafts"                "notmuch://?query=folder:gmail/Drafts" \
"Sent Mail"             "notmuch://?query=folder:gmail/Sent%20Mail" \
"Trash"                 "notmuch://?query=folder:gmail/Trash" \
"Today"                 "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and date:today" \
"Yesterday"             "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and date:yesterday" \
"This Week"             "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and date:this_week" \
"Todo"                  "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and tag:todo" \
"Starred"               "notmuch://?query=to:rsstinnett@gmail.com and tag:star" \
"Burning Man"           'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/Burning%20Man"' \
"  Work List"           'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/Burning%20Man/Work%20List"' \
"ATXHS"                 'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/ATX%20Hackerspace" and not tag:archive' \
"  ATXHS Members"       'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/ATX%20Hackerspace/Members" and not tag:archive' \
"  ATXHS Discuss"       'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/ATX%20Hackerspace/Discuss" and not tag:archive' \
"  ATXHS Announce"      'notmuch://?query=folder:"gmail/ATX%20Hackerspace/Announce" and not tag:archive'
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is a great solution, but I'm super new to awk. It would have taken me hours to work this out one tiny step at a time. I'm actually reading through the O'Reilly Press "Sed and Awk" book right now. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into it.

Comment: You're welcome. For your own sanity don't get caught up in cryptic sed runes - one set of them will do what you want in one sed version, in another version the same script will give you syntax errors or no output, and in others they'll summon Cthulhu. sed is the best tool for doing `s/old/new` on individual strings, for anything that involves more than s, g, and p (with -n) awk or some other tool will be some combination of clearer, simpler, more portable, more efficient, and easier to enhance/maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is another solution using only `sed`. (There is no good reason to use `sed` alone in production, when better tools are available; it's still a good training exercise though.)

Compare to the simple and short solution posted by Enrico De Angelis. There are two differences between his approach and what I propose below.

First, the approach in Enrico's answer would not work if the "replacement" text included spaces (if, for example, each space had to be replaced with `% 20` with a space after the percent sign). Of course, in the OP's problem this is not the case; but in a more general problem, the looping approach in Enrico's solution may lead to infinite loops.

Second, the looping approach requires one run through the regexp matching for each space that must be replaced. By contrast, while the solution below also runs the `s` command several times, it's a fixed number of runs per input line, regardless of the number of spaces to be replaced. Again, in the OP's problem this is a non-issue because there are very few spaces to replace on each line. The approach below may be helpful in more general situations, where there are a large number of replacements needed on each line.

The idea is relatively simple, but the solution is complicated by the fact that `sed` only has two buffers we can work with. Switching back and forth between the two, we can "save" a portion of the string we don't need to touch, and make the changes in the remaining string. Since we only have two buffers and three relevant substrings, we are forced to make "too many changes" in the first half of the solution, and then undo the unneeded changes in the second half. This solution has a glaring weakness too: if the last part of the string already had `%20` in it (past the closing double-quote relevant to `folder`), those will be changed to space, even though they were not spaces in the original.

I wonder if there are better approaches along these lines (meaning, specifically, not involving a looping process).

```
$ sed -E '/folder:"/{h;s/(^.*?folder:").*/\1/;x;s/^.*?folder:"//;s/ /%20/g;x;G;
> /folder:"/s/\n//;h;s/(^.*?folder:"[^"]*").*/\1/;x;s/.*?folder:"[^"]*"//;
> s/%20/ /g;x;G;/folder:"/s/\n//}' inputfile
```

As usual,the leading `$` and `>` are shell prompts (not part of the `sed` command).

**EDIT** As Ed Morton points out in a comment below, lazy quantifiers are a perl feature, not supported in `sed`. That wasn't an essential part of my solution; here is the POSIX ERE - compliant version:

```
$ sed -E '/folder:"/{h;s/(^.*folder:").*/\1/;x;s/^.*folder:"//;s/ /%20/g;x;G;
> /folder:"/s/\n//;h;s/(^.*folder:"[^"]*").*/\1/;x;s/.*folder:"[^"]*"//;
> s/%20/ /g;x;G;/folder:"/s/\n//}' inputfile
```

Comment: [Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) `.*?` is undefined behavior in an ERE (a repetition character following another repetition character) so YMMV with what that'll do. Maybe you were thinking of PCRE syntax where I think that has some defined meaning but I don't know what that is and no sed variant supports PCREs anyway.

Comment: @EdMorton - `.*?` is non-greedy (lazy) quantifier. I thought it came from POSIX ERE, but I was wrong - I just checked; it comes from perl. Indeed, `sed` does not support PCRE. In any case, I used that (and anchoring at the beginning of the string) just for efficiency, it's not essential for the solution.

Comment: With sed I'd have done it exactly like Enrico, but if one really had to avoid a loop then a more straigthforward approach could be `sed -E '/folder:"/ { h ; s/ /%20/g ; G ; s/.*(folder:"[^"]*").*\n(.*)folder:"[^"]*"/\2\1/ }' input_file`.

Comment: @luciole75w - I explained in my answer why I don't like looping: first, if in a more general problem the replacement text includes the match text, we get into an infinite loop; and in general, looping requires one regexp (match + replace) operation for each match, which may be too much if there is a lot of text to replace. As to your alternate solution, the output isn't quite right, but it can probably be fixed. I get the idea, and it is indeed better than mine.

Comment: @mathguy Indeed a parenthesis for the 1st capture was misplaced in my initial comment, I quickly fixed it (hoping nobody was looking ^^) but here the idea was more important than the result as you noticed. I understand your reasons to avoid loops under other circumstances.

Comment: I saw what was wrong too - as I was reading through the code to understand it. I got exactly what I wanted by posting my answer... Ed Morton pointed out that lazy quantifiers are not supported, and you showed a simpler way to do it, exactly in the spirit of what I was trying.

Comment: @mathguy , `sed` is cryptic by itself, but you could format it as one command per line to improve the readability. And by including the continuation prompt `>` you prevent the code from working of someone tries to copy and paste it, so removing those would be an improvement, imho.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis - agreed. I suppose the newlines would get in the way anyway - although perhaps not in this case, due to the grouping operator. Learning the best way to show long commands on stackoverflow. Sometimes I show the line continuation character (backslash at the end of the line) but of course that has the same issue.

Comment: @mathguy you don't need it here, because the command is quoted. You can just hit enter instead of `;`. And maybe add some space for indenting the braced groups appropriately.